# Biblatex: suppress field year when citing books

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to suppress the `year` field when I'm citing  `\ifentrytype{book}`. I thought to be able to use `\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{year}}{}}`, but for some reason it doesn't have the intended effect. Any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks in advance!

I've included a working sample:

EDIT: Now I'm using the `authoryear.cbx`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
citestyle=authoryear,%
bibstyle=authortitle,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
% ===
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:extrainfo:shorttitle}{%
\newunit
\printfield{shorttitle}
}
%
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
       \ifentrytype{book}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:extrainfo:shorttitle}}{}% shorttitle in footnote
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
% ===
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{book}{%
    \clearfield{year}%
  }{%
  }%
}
\makeatother
% ===
% === BIB
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test2,
    author      = {Max Mustermann},
    shortauthor = {M-M},
    title       = {Musterbuch},
    shorttitle  = {MB},
    year        = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
% ===
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
I want to achieve a that if I'm citing a book it won't cite the year. I thought I could achieve that with \verb|\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{year}}{}}|. But it seems like the year is still being printed. Do I have to replace \verb|{year}| with another argument? \\\footcite[p. 85]{test2}
    How can I make it work?
\end{document}
```

Comment: At the moment the citation is generated, in which the hook you chose takes place, the citation uses `labeldate`, so clearing `year` at that point indeed is not much help. There are certainly ways to achieve the result, but you are using an `authoryear` citation style, if you clear the date you will likely end up with ambiguous citations. Are you really, really sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes I need the year gone. But only for entry types `book`. I'm using the authoryear style because it works best with all of my other modifications.

Comment: Well, to get things even more complicated, you have the `comp` variant of `authoryear`, so a lot of possible cases emerge. Technically the place to intervene would be `cite` bibmacro, which you already redefine. You can see there that several cases must be dealt with. E.g. suppose you cite an article and a book by the same author on the same year, should the date be maintained, or excluded? Should the year be present in the bibliography? Should the extradate exist for the book or not? And so on. I really advise against your attempt in these terms...

Comment: All of the changes should only affect the citations. For the bibliography I use another style. In your example, the date would be printed for the article but not for the book. I only want to suppress the year field when I cite books. The change shouldn't affect any other entry types. I think I understand your concerns, but I'm making those changes only for one very specific document where I need it like that.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve, please? What happens if you have to cite two `@book`s by the same author? What happens if you cite a `@book` and an `@article` by the same author (you have a `-comp` style, so normally you'd get "Knuth (1984,1986)", assume the 84 work is a book the 86 work an article, would you want "Knuth (,1986)"  - surely not, what about "Knuth, Knuth (1986)")? May I ask *why* you want to remove the year for `@books` - maybe there is a more elegant way overall to do this, what makes `@book`s special?

Comment: ... I know it is annoying if people question your motives and ask heretical questions, but since the presence of the year is quite integral to the citation style you want to modify, there are quite a few things one has to think about to make sure that doing what you want does not break the overall output of the style or messes up in certain situations.

Comment: After another look at the `biblatex` manual I realized that for citations I’ll be able to use the regular `authoryear` style. And I understand your concerns. I still can’t suppress the year with `clearfield{year}`. And `labelyear` also removes the `author` / `shortauthor`. Basically I’d try to achieve the same result but now with the `authoryear` style.

Comment: `\footcite[85]{test2}` is enough, you don't need to (and should not) include the `p.~` prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need to do is move the `cite:labeldate+extradate` macro from after the conditional into the 'else' branch of the conditional.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%   
     \ifentrytype{book}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:extrainfo:shorttitle}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

Deleting the `year` does not help because the cite commands work with `labelyear`. While `labelyear` may be a copy of `year` (depending on the `\DeclareLabeldate` configuration) it has been defined in a way that removing `year` (at the `biblatex` level) does not influence `labelyear`. So you would have to remove `labelyear` to prevent the date from being printed in citations. But then the `\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}` conditional kicks in and prints the replacement label instead of the `labelname`. This is undesired here. So all in all, it is safest and easiest with the code to not delete any field instead we just don't call the macro that prints the year in citations if we don't want the year.

For your `cite:extrainfo:shorttitle` I'd prefer

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:extrainfo:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
```

This has the advantage that it prints something if you don't give a `shorttitle` field.

[image]

Comment: The result is not very uniform and at least in the example the use of `shorttitle` and `shortauthor` makes the source very, very hard to locate in the bibliography. But maybe the labels are easier to match up with the entries in your actual document.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me. To figure out my redefinitions for `books`, while not messing up already used redefinitions for `articles`. 
In the end I used: 

`\ifentrytype{book}
{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}} {}` I had to exclude `{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}` completely.

Comment: Concerning the `shorttitle` and `shortauthor`. I'm currently working on creating a `biblatex`/`biber` configuration for german law documents, because I'm unhappy with all `bibtex`solutions.
For german law documents there are strict requirements and I'm using the `shorttitle` and `shortauthor` fields to achieve those

Comment: @texnewbie Mhhh, but if you remove `\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}` completely, there is little point in using an `authoryear`-like style in the first place? Ah yes, law citations, apparently everyone has their own strict guidelines that people must abide by. Unfortunately, the two 'jura' styles for `biblatex` have not been updated in a very long time and should not be used any more. If you come up with something stable *and* want to maintain it for the foreseeable future, you may want to consider releasing your work when you are done.

Comment: I reintroduce `\usebibmacro{labeldate+extradate}` for `\ifentrytype{article}`. 

We'll see if I get there lot's of work to do :) And I'll have to figure out how to create a style `.cbx`/`.bbx` file. Because right now I'm only using a `biblatex.cfg` and a `.tex` file with renewments.