# Omit year in \cite command (Overleaf) LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer, citing, missing

I have a trouble with citation in Beamer class.

First, I would like to ask if there is a way to omit the year

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
     \cite{lee2015cyber} \par
     some random texts some random texts some random texts some random texts \cite{lee2015cyber}
\end{frame}
```

Above is an example of my code.
The result I get is [image]

I prefer the output is just *Lee et al.* or, *Lee et al. (2015)*. (The `\parencite` command wrap entire citation in the parentheses)

Then, when I use the same citation multiple times on one page, or sometimes the citation is in caption/long text, it just displays the year, no information regarding authors.
I would like to ask how to deal with these problems.
In the preamble, I just use:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,citetracker=true,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: this should meet the requirement   -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429040/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438973/197451

Comment: @jsbibra thank you for your reply, I also checked that thread. The solution is not so uniform and only for book.